# Compiling an iPhone XCode project to work on Android

Tags: iphone, android, xcode, compilation

I have an iPhone app which is written in XCode and is currently selling on the iTunes app store. I want to be able to release it for the Android market. Is there any way to compile my app from XCode to work on the Android operating system. I don't really want to learn a new language and completely rewrite my app, so was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: scade.io -> give it a look

Answer (score 7):

There isn't any way to compile Android apps from Xcode, and i strongly doubt that Apple would introduce such a feature - if it's even technically possible to do. Sorry.

But if you have Objective C down, you shouldn't have to much problems understanding Java (which is used for creating Android apps).

Check the link below for a pretty comprehensive guide to start learning java and code for the Android platform:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-tutorial/

Good luck!

Comment: So all of the apps that are out there for both platforms, Angry Birds for example, which look almost identical are written twice, once for each platform?

Comment: Correct, it isn't unusual to have different teams working on the same game for different platforms. Usually you only share server-side code and various graphical assets.

Comment: I have worked on apps like these, and yes, we make the project twice, one for each platform.
(sometimes thrice, if we need black berry)

Comment: OK. So I've had a search on the net and found 'Eclipse' and the Android SDK. Is Eclipse the way to go? And if so, do I need to download Eclipse Classic or Eclipse IDE for Java? Will I be able to pick up Java fairly quickly if I can code in Obj-C? The syntax looks fairly similar!

Comment: Yup, eclipse with java is the way to go about it. There are several video tutorials on youtube which should help you out with setting it up together with the android sdk. Java is a very good and easy language to learn, I'm sure you'll be writing killer android apps in no time. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll download Eclipse and the Android SDK and start coding. I'm hoping I can copy and paste my methods from XCode into Eclipse and then change the syntax of each line, as Java looks fairly similar to Obj C. Obviously without the square brackets [ and ]

Comment: I know this is an old post. I would now recommend Android Studio :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, in general you can't do this. Even if assuming Objective-C can be compiled/converted into Java (which is most likely will not be true for times to come), you'll need to rewrite UI part; then most of OS APIs are different too. There are several features that iOS has that Android lacks or does not have open API for it, or has limited API, or has conceptually different or just different API.

Its just easier to move some of your iOS code into C/C++ shared library and then make sure that it compiles and works on both platforms. And then make platform dependent pieces separately for each platform (UI, hardware related stuff, etc.). This way you'll have at least part of your code shared.

Comment: "There several features that iOS has that Android lacks or does not have open API for it,"


it should be noted that the opposite is also true.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely true, But there is no way to use those non-existent feature on iOS :), so he does not need to worry about them when porting his app.